# Initializing swiper sliders dynamically unexplainable behaviour

Tags: javascript, dynamic, swiper.js

I have to create instances of swiper dynamically. These swipers have dynamically filled image contents. I have been fighting this the whole day with my lacking skills and cannot get this to work.

There are no javascript console errors, so I am assuming something is very fundamentally wrong but I don't know what it is.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- The sliders are initiated very standard way, i skipped showing them. These are my paginations where I cannot get the pagination to be rendered -->

<div class="secondary-0 swiper-pagination-clickable swiper-pagination-bullets"></div>
<div class="secondary-1 swiper-pagination-clickable swiper-pagination-bullets"></div>
<div class="secondary-2 swiper-pagination-clickable swiper-pagination-bullets"></div>

<script>
    // I get lots of image data from php here
    var imagearrays = <?php echo json_encode( $images_multiarray_js ); ?>;

    // initialize variables for use in the loop. 
    var i;
    var subNameArray = [];
    var subSwiper = [];

    // Loop through the imagearrays variable and initiate swipers.
    for (i = 0; i < imagearrays.length; i++) {
        subNameArray[i] = imagearrays[i].imagenames;
        subSwiper = new Swiper('.subswiper-' + i, { // all my swiper-containers have extra class "subswiper-0" "subswiper-1" etc.
            pagination: { // my main issue: I cannot get this pagination to render. WHY?
                el: '.secondary-' + i, //my paginations have class like "secondary-0"
                clickable: true,
                renderBullet: function (index, className) {
                    return '<span class="' + className + '"><div class="pagination-ball"></div>' + subNameArray[index] + '</span>';
                }
            },
            loop:true,
            effect: 'fade',
            clickable:true,
            disableOnInteraction:false,
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is what my imagearrays variable looks like, just to show you that it's fine.

```
[
  {"controllertype":false,"imagenames":["name1","name2"]},
  {"controllertype":true,"imagenames":["name3","name4"]},
  {"controllertype":false,"imagenames":["name5","name6"]}
]
```

I tried to go line by line in debugging JS mode, but it looks like the console simply leaps over the "new Swiper(..." line and everything inside it. Again, no errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

How to feel really stupid:

1. Spend half a day figuring out why your code doesn't work
2. On a whim go check that your swiper selector class is attached to the correct html element and realize that it is not
3. Go cry in stackoverflow

I'm sorry guys, this question is useless. Everything works as intended with that d'oh fix.